# Is there an elegant proof of this elementary bifurcation theory result?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let's suppose I have a $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $(x,\lambda)\mapsto f(x,\lambda)$.  Suppose there is a unique solution of the equation $f(x,\lambda_1)=0$, and either zero or more than one solution of the equation $f(x,\lambda_2)=0$, where, say, $\lambda_1<\lambda_2$.  I've laboriously proven to myself that at least one of the following must occur.

1. There exists $\lambda^*\in[\lambda_1,\lambda_2]$ and $x^*\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x^*,\lambda^*)=0$ and $\partial_x f(x^*,\lambda^*)=0$.
2. The set $\{x\in\mathbb{R} : f(x,\lambda)=0, \lambda\in[\lambda_1,\lambda_2]\}$ is unbounded.

The unsatisfactory thing is that my proof is a good three pages of nit-pick cases, endless use of the implicit function theorem and several awkward sequence constructions.  The proof could be shortened by sufficient hand-waving, but I wanted to do it right.

Is there a "nice" proof of this?  Any reference would be helpful (I'm not exactly sure what the search terms should be.. :S).  Or, is the result incorrect, and something went terribly wrong in my proof?

Comment: I might be wrong, but first part seems a little bit tautological for me. Just take the $x^\ast$ and $\lambda^\ast$ such that $f(x^\ast, \lambda_1) = 0$. If you consider $y(x) = f(x, \lambda_1)$ then $x^\ast$ is clearly an extremum of this function: this follows from uniqueness requirement of solution of equation $f(x, \lambda_1) = 0$. From this follows that $\partial_{x} f(x, \lambda) \vert_{(x^\ast, \lambda_1)} = 0$ and it always holds.

Comment: Also, if you'll try to tighten the first alternative (i.e., replacing condition $\lambda^\ast \in \lbrack \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \rbrack$ with $\lambda^\ast \in ( \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \rbrack$, then there is an example for which both of alternatives fail. Consider function $f(x, \lambda) = x^2 - \lambda$.

Comment: @Evgeny The first part is not tautological.  The hypothesis is that there is exactly 1 solution of $f(x,\lambda_1)=0$, and $m\neq 1$ solutions of $f(x,\lambda_2)=0$.  A priori, we do not know where the number of solutions changes.  As per your first suggestion, take $f(x,\lambda)=x(x^2+1-\lambda)$ with $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_1=2$.  There is exactly one solution, $x^*=0$, when $\lambda=1$, and three solutions when $\lambda=2$, but $x^*=0$ is not an extremum of $y(x)=f(x,1)=x(x^2+1)$, and in particular, $\partial_x f(x^*,\lambda_1)=1\neq 0$.

Comment: A typo above...
"...There is exactly one solution when **$\lambda=0$**..."

Comment: You're right, I've forgot that there could be a simple root at $\lambda_1 = 0$.. As for the first part, if branching happens at point that previously was a unique solution (as in your's and mine examples), some sort of Newton method can be used to prove that derivative should vanish somewhere: if derivative doesn't vanish, applying Newton's method of root finding tells you that zero-solution is unique in some neighboorhood which contradicts branching.

Comment: Also, can you provide an example which satisfies second alternative and fails the first one?

Comment: Certainly.  $f(x,\lambda)=x(1-\lambda x)$ with $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=1$ (or any $\lambda_2>0$) works here.  When $\lambda=0$, there is a single root at $x=0$, there are exactly two roots when $\lambda=1$, but the partial derivative is $f_x=1-2x\lambda$, which only vanishes when $x=\frac{1}{2\lambda}$, but this is not a root of $f(\cdot,\lambda)$.